# Two listviews with a static button above

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Using a RelativeLayout I can have a static button on top of 2 listvies side by side, however only the left listview gets displayed.

If I put the two listvies in a Linear Layout they don't seem to display correctly either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/new_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myButton"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/new_page"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_view_right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/list_view_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/new_page"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use frame layout for this if your problem does not solve. see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm) how to use frame layout .

Answer (score 0):

add

android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_view_left"

to your second List view (that is at the right side).

you will start to view your second list view.

and as the width is wrap content, so you need to take care the width of each item in list view 1, else you can not see the other listview.